# Unique combinations from 7 items where repetition is allowed, and order doesn't matter

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to calculate the number of unique combinations from a 7-element set where repetition is allowed and order doesn't matter.

**For example:** Suppose $S = \{a, b, c, d, e, f, g\}$, and I want 3 items per set.

- $aaa$ is valid.
- $aab$ is valid.
- $aab = aba = baa$ (these three outputs should only count as 1 combination)

I know I have to start with the total number of possible combinations ($7^n$) and remove the ones that are duplicates by nature, however I am blanking on how to handle the removal of duplicates (due to order not mattering).

Answer (score 1):

This is the "multiset" problem and is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676109/how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-a-multiset) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: No it is not, look again

Comment: You may want to clarify the question, as your example looks like it has the solution 7 multichoose 3. Perhaps you're after the powerset of the multiset or the unordered tuples(S,k)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be conceived as placing 3 identical balls into 7 distinct bins,

and solved using "stars and bars" [explained here](http://jhyun95.hubpages.com/hub/Stars-and-Bars-Combinatorics) as **${(3+7-1)\choose(7-1}$** = 84

Just verifying by a longer method, you could categorise as

*3 of a kind*: **${7\choose 1} = 7$**

*2-1 of a kind*: **${7\choose 1}\cdot{6\choose 1} = 42$**

*1-1-1 of a kind*: **${7\choose 3}= 35$**

*Total # of combinations*: **84**